# Odd lambda issue (compiler bug?)

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, g++, segmentation-fault

I have a piece of code which is failing during runtime with various strange memory corruption stuff.  I've narrowed it down to this section of code:

```
List<CollisionBlock> WorldClient::getCollisionBlocks(RectF const& boundBox, bool doSort, Vec2F sortCenter) const {
  auto res = m_collisionGenerator.getPolys(boundBox);

  if (doSort) {
    sort(res, [=](CollisionBlock const& block1, CollisionBlock const& block2) {
    return magSquared(sortCenter - block1.poly.center()) < magSquared(sortCenter - block2.poly.center());
      });
  }

  return res;
}
```

If I remove the `const&` from the lambda the code works fine.  I don't know why.  I was wondering if I ran into a compiler bug, or if there's something obvious that I'm overlooking.

Here's the definition for CollisionBlock:

```
struct CollisionBlock {
  PolyF poly;
  // Will never be None
  CollisionKind kind;
  // Normalzied vector encoding the slope of the block we collided with.
  // Always faces right, y component can be positive or negative.
  Vec2F slope;
};
```

I can reproduce on Linux 32-bit (g++ version 4.7.0 and 4.6.3), MacOSX (unsure word size and g++ version), Windows 7 64-bit (g++ version 4.6.3), Windows 7 32-bit (g++ versions 4.6.2 and 4.6.3), but not Linux 64-bit (g++ version 4.6.1).

I'm using C++11, not boost.

`Poly::center()`

```
Coord center() const {
  return sum(m_vertexes) / (DataType)m_vertexes.size();
}
```

`sum`

```
template<typename Container>
typename Container::value_type sum(Container const& cont) {
  return reduce(cont, std::plus<typename Container::value_type>());
}
```

`reduce`

```
// Somewhat nicer form of std::accumulate
template<typename Container, typename Function>
typename Container::value_type reduce(Container const& l, Function f) {
  typename Container::const_iterator i = l.begin();
  typename Container::value_type res{};

  if (i == l.end())
    return res;

  res = *i++;
  while (i != l.end())
    res = f(res, *i++);
  return res;
}
```

`sort`

```
template<typename Container, typename Compare>
void sort(Container& c, Compare comp) {
  std::sort(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
}
```

There's quite a bit going on with this question.  Sorry, I'll try to work out a smaller test case.

UPDATE:

Replacing the call to `sum` in `Poly::center` with `std::accumulate` does not help.

Comment: What does `PolyF::center` look like? Does it operate differently on a const object versus a non-const object? Does it try to cache the result in the object?

Comment: Added the code in question to the post.

Comment: Clearly the `sort` you're calling is not `std::sort`, so what is it?

Comment: ildjarn, it's a wrapper around `std::sort`.  I added the code to the post.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you've posted, but it isn't complete enough to compile.  Can you create a minimal complete example?

Comment: My geuss is that whatever the definition of

Comment: @VaughnCato, I'll give it a shot, but thus far it's resisted my attempts to simplify.

Comment: Is it possible there's a floating point precision issue with the comparator?  If, due to roundoff error the comparator isn't a strict weak order (say that it reports a<b<c<...<a), you could run into a crash.  Whether or not you get a crash could be very sensitive to platform and compile options.  This might happen if, for example, you had two polygons whose centers were almost exactly equidistant from `sortCenter`

Comment: Or even more, if your default initialization of `res` in `reduce` isn't the same thing as zero-initializing it.  I've run into that isse before, and it would probably depend on your implementation of `Vec2f`

Comment: The other variables that you use in your lambda, are they bound to `this`? If so, try to pass `this` explicitly with `[this]` to the lambda and explicitly call them via `this->member`. I had a similar issue a while back where that solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that the error is outside of the code you have posted.  You could take my dummy code below & slowly morph it into your real code until it starts exhibiting the problem. Please let us know if you find it, I'm quite curious.

FYI, I had to make up code in several places to get anything near what you are doing.  All this really does is exercise the small bits of code you posted.

```
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef double mocish;

typedef int CollisionKind; //is actually enum class
typedef mocish RectF;

class Vec2F {
public:
  Vec2F() {
    vertexes.push_back(0);
    vertexes.push_back(0);
  }
  Vec2F(float a, float b) {
    vertexes.push_back(a);
    vertexes.push_back(b);
  }

  float operator[](unsigned index) const {
    return vertexes[index];
  }

  float operator[](unsigned index) {
    return vertexes[index];
  }

  Vec2F operator+(Vec2F const& other) const {
    return Vec2F(vertexes[0]+other[0], vertexes[1]+other[1]);
  }

  Vec2F operator-(Vec2F const& other) const {
    return Vec2F(vertexes[0]-other[0], vertexes[1]-other[1]);
  }

  Vec2F operator*(float other) const {
    return Vec2F(vertexes[0]*other, vertexes[1]*other);
  }

  Vec2F operator/(float other) const {
    return Vec2F(vertexes[0]/other, vertexes[1]/other);
  }

  Vec2F operator=(Vec2F const& other) {
    vertexes[0] = other[0];
    vertexes[1] = other[1];
    return *this;
  }

private:
  std::deque<float> vertexes;
};

float magSquared(Vec2F const& a) {
  return a[0]*a[0]+a[1]*a[1];
}

typedef Vec2F Coord;

// Somewhat nicer form of std::accumulate
template<typename Container, typename Function>
typename Container::value_type reduce(Container const& l, Function f) {
  typename Container::const_iterator i = l.begin();
  typename Container::value_type res{};

  if (i == l.end())
    return res;

  res = *i++;
  while (i != l.end())
    res = f(res, *i++);
  return res;
}     


template<typename Container>
typename Container::value_type sum(Container const& cont) {
  return reduce(cont, std::plus<typename Container::value_type>());
}


struct PolyF
{
    PolyF()
    {
        m_vertexes.resize(4);
        std::generate( m_vertexes.begin(), m_vertexes.end(), [](){ return Vec2F(std::rand(), std::rand());} );
    }

    std::vector<Coord> m_vertexes;

    Coord center() const 
    {
      return sum(m_vertexes) / (float)m_vertexes.size();
    }
};

struct CollisionBlock 
{
  PolyF poly;
  // Will never be None
  CollisionKind kind;
  // Normalzied vector encoding the slope of the block we collided with.
  // Always faces right, y component can be positive or negative.
  Vec2F slope;
};


template<typename Container, typename Compare>
void sort(Container& c, Compare comp) {
  std::sort(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
} 

struct CollisionGen
{
    std::deque<CollisionBlock> getPolys( RectF const& ) const
    {
        std::deque<CollisionBlock> collision_block_moc(50);
        return collision_block_moc;
    }
};

struct WorldClient
{
    CollisionGen m_collisionGenerator;


    std::deque<CollisionBlock> getCollisionBlocks(RectF const& boundBox, bool doSort, Vec2F sortCenter) const 
    {
      auto res = m_collisionGenerator.getPolys(boundBox);

    //auto test = magSquared(sortCenter - res.front().poly.center()) < magSquared(sortCenter - res.front().poly.center());

      if (doSort) {
        sort(res, [=](CollisionBlock const& block1, CollisionBlock const& block2) {
        return magSquared(sortCenter - block1.poly.center()) < magSquared(sortCenter - block2.poly.center());
          });
      }

      return res;
    }
};

    int main() 
    {
        WorldClient wc;
        while (true) {
          wc.getCollisionBlocks( 42.0, true, {0,0} );
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've edited your post and added some bits/pieces to get it to compile and work kinda like the code in question works.  However, it does not exhibit the symptoms I was having in the real code.

Comment: Did you find it? What was it?

Comment: Memory corruption from elsewhere.  It just so happened to show only on 32-bit, and only when I used const.  Weird.  Also valgrind didn't detect it.  Double weird.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the iterators on your template List<> are not random access iterators, which std::sort requires, Note that std::list only provides bidirectional iteration.

If you've implemented your own list, I would suggest heavily scrutinizing your iterator implementation to make sure that it is correct and provides a full & correct implementation of the random access iterator concept.

Comment: Sorry, `List` is actually a wrapper around `std::deque` in our codebase.  Not around `std::list` as might be expected.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you are passing by value to the lambdas by saying [=] but using references. Either you should change that, or pass values by using std::ref to really use the intended reference to the instance itself.

Comment: I did notice that, but the `[=]` part of the lambda refers to values not passed to the function (in this case it's there so I can use `sortCenter`).  Moreover, it doesn't work when I specify `[&]` or specify only sortCenter by value or reference.

Answer (score 0):

Is your comparator a strict weak order?  Does it consistantly order its inputs?  I suspect that you're not actually zero-initializing `res` in `reduce`, and so `center()` ends up returning garbage.  This should be easy to check generically-ish:  add an `assert(f(res,res) == res)` right after the declaration of res.

If the comparator is not consistant, you run into undefined behavior using `std::sort`, which can easily result in a crash.  And be sensitive to platform, optimizations,etc.